# iPhone 6 Video Pulse

Tags: iphone

Does anyone know what this strange effect is in my video?  It's almost as if something is causing the video to "pulse" and reset somehow.  At first, I thought perhaps my own heartbeat was causing a slight vibration resulting in this but the first video was taken with the phone on a stand:

You may have to watch kind of closely to see it but I think it's pretty pronounced in the grass, trees, and cherry blossoms at HD and full screen.

It seems like the video is alternating between sharp and soft so I guess it's just an artifact of the compression but I haven't noticed the effect being so bad in other videos.

Is there anything I can do to fix this?

Comment: it looks like its the iPhone auto focus, try finding an app that doesn't use the auto focus

Comment: Ah, so simple and yet I never thought of it.  I think you're right and I'll give a different app a try.  This might be so simple as to not be of much help to others but please do put in your comment as an answer and I'll give it the up vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like its the iPhone auto focus, try finding an app that doesn't use the auto focus